# Search for an excell table's content

Tags: windows

How can I search for a content in Windows 10 pro?
For example I search for an excell table's content... how can search for it ? Should I use something special caracter?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZ8fg.png)
Wxcell

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), ***read about what's on-topic in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)***, and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to do this is to enable the option in Windows to search inside the contents of the file which can be done through the Indexing Options.

Here is a link to a website that explains how to do this.

https://www.howtogeek.com/99406/how-to-search-for-text-inside-of-any-file-using-windows-search/